# Remove Mac maximize window left margin

Tags: macos, window-manager

When maximizing a Mac window with the green button, it will not maximize to full size, but have a little left margin from the left side.

[image: Window with left margin]

I guess there is no setting to change that, but that margin has to have a specific size defined. Is there any kind of terminal command I can run to decrease the left margin to 0?

I know there are apps which can position windows to any prefered position and size, but I is there a way to do it without one?

The strange thing is, that it does maximize to full size without a margin on the right screen when you've got a second display connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4 pixel margin is shown on the side of the screen the Dock is on.

I don't know any way to remove it other than to disable Dock:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Dock.plist
```

However that also disables Mission Control and the application switcher, and it makes full screen windows stop working.

Comment: Ah ok, the effect is also gone, if you're moving the Dock to the bottom.

Comment: Sp the margin is needed as a target for your mouse to put the dock in view. If you want full screen hot the full screen arrows at top right - OSX is not Windows

Comment: Ok, so there's a reason for the margin and it isn't a good idea to remove it anyway.